# (Javascript) How do I show the current score on the page with my craps game?

Tags: javascript, display

currently my game is finished but the only way a player can see their score is through alert boxes when they either roll the dice, upgrade or quit the game, I'm trying to figure out how to add a live score on the page so it's easier to keep track.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated! I tried a document.write method but it deleted my whole game and just displayed the results so I'm a bit lost on this.

```js
var myscore = 0;
var housescore = 0;
var dicesides = 6;

function rollDice() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * dicesides) + 1;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * dicesides) + 1;

  var total = x + y;
  msg = "You rolled " + x + ", " + y + " = " + total + "\n";
  if (total != 11 && total < 7 && x != y) {
    housescore += 1;
    msg += "Even Up";
  } else if (total != 11 && total > 7 && x != y) {
    myscore += 1;
    msg += "Player Up";
  }
  if (total == 7 || total == 11) {
    housescore += 10;
    msg += "CRAPS";
  } else if (x == y) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
      myscore += 10;
      msg += "Even Up";
    } else {
      housescore += 10;
      msg += "Odd Ball";
    }
  }
  msg += " Your Score is " + "Player: " + myscore + ", House: " + housescore;
  alert(msg);
  didIwin();

}

function didIwin() {
  if (housescore >= 100) {
    alert("Sorry the house won the game!");
  } else if (playerscore >= 100) {
    alert("Congratulations you won the game!");
  }
  myscore = 0;
  housescore = 0;
  dicesides = 6;
}

function promoteDice() {
  if (myscore >= 10) {
    dicesides += 1;
    myscore -= 10;
    alert("Your Dice now have " + dicesides + " sides" + " You have " + myscore + " points remaining.");
  } else {
    difference = 10 - myscore;
    alert("You need " + difference + " more points");
  }
}

function demoteDice() {
  if (myscore >= 10) {
    dicesides -= 1;
    myscore -= 10;
    alert("Your Dice now have " + dicesides + " sides." + " You have " + myscore + " points remaining.");
  } else {
    difference = 10 - myscore;
    alert("You need " + difference + " more points");
  }
}

function addRoll() {
  if (myscore >= 50) {
    rollDice();
    rollDice();
    myscore -= 50;
    alert("Nice double roll! You have " + myscore + " points remaining.");
  } else {
    difference = 50 - myscore;
    alert("You need " + difference + " more points");
  }
}

function quit() {
  alert(" Your Score is " + "Player: " + myscore + ", House: " + housescore);
  alert("The game is now reset");
  myscore = 0;
  housescore = 0;
  dicesides = 6;
}
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#" onclick="rollDice();">Roll</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="quit();">Exit</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Upgrade
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#" onclick="promoteDice();">Add a side to your Dice</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="demoteDice();">Remove a side to your Dice</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="addRoll();">Add an additional Roll</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Welcome to the Craps game!</h3>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pure Javascript

You can use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get the element, and [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to change the text of the element.

I created an `updateHTML()` function for you which updates the html for you.

```js
var myscore = 0;
var housescore = 0;
var dicesides = 6;
var myScoreElement = document.getElementById("myScore");
var houseScoreElement = document.getElementById("houseScore");

function rollDice() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * dicesides) + 1;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * dicesides) + 1;

  var total = x + y;
  msg = "You rolled " + x + ", " + y + " = " + total + "\n";
  if (total != 11 && total < 7 && x != y) {
    housescore += 1;
    msg += "Even Up";
  } else if (total != 11 && total > 7 && x != y) {
    myscore += 1;
    msg += "Player Up";
  }
  if (total == 7 || total == 11) {
    housescore += 10;
    msg += "CRAPS";
  } else if (x == y) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
      myscore += 10;
      msg += "Even Up";
    } else {
      housescore += 10;
      msg += "Odd Ball";
    }
  }
  msg += " Your Score is " + "Player: " + myscore + ", House: " + housescore;
  alert(msg);

  updateHTML();

  didIwin();

}

function didIwin() {
  if (housescore >= 100) {
    alert("Sorry the house won the game!");
  } else if ( /*this should be myscore*/ myscore >= 100) {
    alert("Congratulations you won the game!");
  }
  myscore = 0;
  housescore = 0;
  dicesides = 6;
}

function promoteDice() {
  if (myscore >= 10) {
    dicesides += 1;
    myscore -= 10;
    alert("Your Dice now have " + dicesides + " sides" + " You have " + myscore + " points remaining.");
  } else {
    difference = 10 - myscore;
    alert("You need " + difference + " more points");
  }
  updateHTML();
}

function demoteDice() {
  if (myscore >= 10) {
    dicesides -= 1;
    myscore -= 10;
    alert("Your Dice now have " + dicesides + " sides." + " You have " + myscore + " points remaining.");
  } else {
    difference = 10 - myscore;
    alert("You need " + difference + " more points");
  }
  updateHTML();
}

function addRoll() {
  if (myscore >= 50) {
    rollDice();
    rollDice();
    myscore -= 50;
    alert("Nice double roll! You have " + myscore + " points remaining.");
  } else {
    difference = 50 - myscore;
    alert("You need " + difference + " more points");
  }
  updateHTML();
}

function quit() {
  alert(" Your Score is " + "Player: " + myscore + ", House: " + housescore);
  alert("The game is now reset");
  myscore = 0;
  housescore = 0;
  dicesides = 6;
  updateHTML();
}

//This is what I added
function updateHTML() {
  myScoreElement.innerHTML = "My Score: " + myscore;
  houseScoreElement.innerHTML = "House Score: " + housescore;
}
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#" onclick="rollDice();">Roll</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="quit();">Exit</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Upgrade
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#" onclick="promoteDice();">Add a side to your Dice</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="demoteDice();">Remove a side to your Dice</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="addRoll();">Add an additional Roll</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Welcome to the Craps game!</h3>
  <h3 id="myScore">My Score: </h3>
  <h3 id="houseScore">House Score: </h3>
</body>

</html>
```

## jQuery

You can also use [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/) like below. This uses jQuery selectors `#` to select the element, and [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) to change the text of the element.

I also added [fancy ES6 template literals.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings) They're extremely useful, and I highly suggest you check them out.

`"Code " + variable + " More Code"` is the same as `` `Code ${variable} Mode Code` ``

```js
var myscore = 0;
var housescore = 0;
var dicesides = 6;

function rollDice() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * dicesides) + 1;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * dicesides) + 1;

  var total = x + y;
  msg = `You rolled ${x}, ${y} = ${total} \n`;
  if (total != 11 && total < 7 && x != y) {
    housescore += 1;
    msg += "Even Up";
  } else if (total != 11 && total > 7 && x != y) {
    myscore += 1;
    msg += "Player Up";
  }
  if (total == 7 || total == 11) {
    housescore += 10;
    msg += "CRAPS";
  } else if (x == y) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
      myscore += 10;
      msg += "Even Up";
    } else {
      housescore += 10;
      msg += "Odd Ball";
    }
  }
  msg += ` Your Score is Player: ${myscore}, House: ${housescore}`;
  alert(msg);

  updateHTML();

  didIwin();

}

function didIwin() {
  if (housescore >= 100) {
    alert("Sorry the house won the game!");
  } else if ( /*this should be myscore*/ myscore >= 100) {
    alert("Congratulations you won the game!");
  }
  myscore = 0;
  housescore = 0;
  dicesides = 6;
}

function promoteDice() {
  if (myscore >= 10) {
    dicesides += 1;
    myscore -= 10;
    alert(`Your Dice now have ${diceside} sides You have ${myscore} points remaining.`);
  } else {
    difference = 10 - myscore;
    alert(`You need ${difference} more points`);
  }
  updateHTML();
}

function demoteDice() {
  if (myscore >= 10) {
    dicesides -= 1;
    myscore -= 10;
    alert(`Your Dice now have ${dicesides} sides. You have ${myscore} points remaining.`);
  } else {
    difference = 10 - myscore;
    alert(`You need ${difference} more points`);
  }
  updateHTML();
}

function addRoll() {
  if (myscore >= 50) {
    rollDice();
    rollDice();
    myscore -= 50;
    alert(`Nice double roll! You have ${myscore} points remaining.`);
  } else {
    difference = 50 - myscore;
    alert(`You need ${difference} more points`);
  }
  updateHTML();
}

function quit() {
  alert(` Your Score is Player: ${myscore}, House: ${housescore}`);
  alert("The game is now reset");
  myscore = 0;
  housescore = 0;
  dicesides = 6;
  updateHTML();
}

//This is what I added
function updateHTML() {
  $("#myScore").html(`My Score: ${myscore}`);
  $("#houseScore").html(`House Score: ${housescore}`);
}
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  $("#myDropdown").toggleClass("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
$(window).click(function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = $("#myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.hasClass('show')) {
      myDropdown.removeClass('show');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#" onclick="rollDice();">Roll</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="quit();">Exit</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Upgrade
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#" onclick="promoteDice();">Add a side to your Dice</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="demoteDice();">Remove a side to your Dice</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="addRoll();">Add an additional Roll</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Welcome to the Craps game!</h3>
  <h3 id="myScore">My Score: </h3>
  <h3 id="houseScore">House Score: </h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You rock man this is so clean and useful I am so happy you showed me this!

Comment: @JonFrank Your welcome. Accept the answer so everyone else knows that this solution worked for you as well. I'll add another solution using jQuery right now, which may help you even more

Comment: Wow Jquery looks even simpler, I like it!

Comment: @JonFrank give me a few minutes. I'm going to completely update your code to jQuery for that second solution. It will make your life much easier

Comment: Sweet ok I appreciate it

Comment: @JonFrank done. I also added fance ES6 template literals, which makes it so much easier to add code.